# Почему PyCharm ругается, но всё равно потом выводит результат?

Tags: python, pycharm, for

Задача: вывести каждый элемент списка вместе с его индексом.

```py
spisok = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']  # создаём список элементов  

a = (len(spisok) + 1)                   # "a" равно фактической длине списка  
for i in range(a):                      # в переменную "i" перебираем цифры от 0 до "a"  
    print(spisok[i], i)                 # напечатать элемент списка "i" и его индекс
```

Comment: у вас итерирование в цикле до элемента с индексом `5`, а в вашем списке индекс последнего элемента `4`

Comment: Понятно! Значит len - длина строки 5, а rаnge перебирает индексы от 0 до 4, не включая 5, поэтому не нужно страховать len дополнительной единичкой, всё и так стыкуется и работает. Спасибо!

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: А что такое _PyCharm ругается_, так и выводит: "Сегодня ругаюсь"?

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь встроенной функцией [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i,x in enumerate(spisok):
    print(x, i)
```

вывод:

```
one 0
two 1
three 2
four 3
five 4
```